# how to import CSVreader feature in my java code? For whatever reason I can't use the cvsreader feature

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, jar, output

Basically I'm trying to write a converter in Java, the output will be transformed into CSV format.

This is the line where I have error:

```
import com.csvreader.*;
```

I downloaded the jar of csv and I added it to my path, still won't work. Maybe I used the wrong jar?

Also is there a import feature that will convert or read csv feature in eclipse that doesn't involve downloading jar?

Comment: What kind od error do you get? You have some import issue

Comment: @jerome hey sir this is not a duplicate, i:m not sure what jar I used.

Comment: @Nemus hey sir just showing error that I can't use the csvreader import feature. Is there way to import without using a jar? or I used the wrong jar.